# Can I create threads in App Enging using Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine

Can this code create threads in Google App Engine. If no, why not?
    class LogText(db.Model):
        content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadname):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name=threadname)
    def run(self,request):
        log=LogText()
        log.content=request.POST.get('content',None)
        log.put()

def Log(request):
    thr = MyThread('haha')
    thr.run(request)

    return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: Not sure which Python version you were using, but this wouldn't run in parallel with Python 2.7 and 3.x -- you'd block on `thr.run(request`. Instead, you should start a thread with `t.start()`.

Answer (score 2):

App Engine does not allow you to create new threads, probably because primarily the goal of App Engine is to build simple request-response apps, and threads are usually not considered "simple".

Managing threads for an app to prevent abuse (accidental or otherwise) would be difficult, or impossible, for App Engine to do, so they just disallow them entirely.

Comment: This answer is a little out of date. The new Python 2.7 runtime will support multithreading - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/newin27.html#Multithreading